# Find Match and Output Value VBA

Tags: vba, loops

I want to search through a catalogue of data (contained in "Catalogue" and if that data matches the item in Cell "D3" I want to output the value "Mobile Phone" into Cell "H3" in "Sheet1".

Here's what I'm working with:

```
Sub VBAScanner()

    Dim productname As String
    Dim finalrow As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    finalrow = Sheets("Catalogue").Range("J3000").End(x1UP).Row
    productname = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D3").Value

    For i = 5 To finalrow

        If Sheets("Catalogue").Cells(i, 5) = productname Then

            Sheets("Sheet1").Cell("H3").Value = "Mobile Phone"

            End If

        Next i

End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: x1UP should be xlUP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Find for this as well as correct for `xlUp`. Also, add in some basic tests for not found, last row being less than 5, or `productname` being blank.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub VBAScanner()
    Dim productname As String, finalRow As Long, found As Range, i As Long

    productname = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D3").Value
    If productname = vbNullString Then Exit Sub

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Catalogue")
        finalRow = .Range("J3000").End(xlUp).Row
        If finalRow < 5 Then Exit Sub
        Set found = .Range("J5:J" & finalRow).Find(productname)
    End With

    If Not found Is Nothing Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H3").Value = "Mobile Phone"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: In this instance you've used 'If Not found is Nothing Then...' is this saying if the value is null, because it is not in the set 'found' then output "Mobile Phone"?

Comment: If the productname is not found in .Range("J5:J" & finalRow) then found will be nothing as it will not be set to a range being returned by .Find  . Test is saying, if  Not Nothing i.e. productname was in the range searched and now found has been set to the cell where found and is no longer nothing which is what it was initialized as.